# How to reset (clean up) delta table log, but keep the data

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, delta-lake

Let's say I'm at the point where delta log of delta table has become too big, and I'm 100% confident that it's OK to treat the current version of table as version 0 and discard delta log for good. What's the best way to clean up, reset delta log but keep the data? It's OS delta on S3.